# missing 1 required positional argument 'b'

Tags: python, list

```
import re
class work:

    def a(self, i):
            i = 10
            j = 12

            self.i = i
            self.match(i)

            self.j = j
            self.match(j)


    def match(self, a, b):
            print("this is I", a) 
            print("this is J", b)

x = work()
x.a(0)

self.match(i)
TypeError: match() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

trying to Import `i`  and `j` for matching! any help

Answer (score 1):

You are giving two arguments in the function definition:

```
 def match(self, a, b):
    print("this is I", a) 
    print("this is J", b)
```

, but only giving one in its call:

```
 self.match(j)
```